# Split collected date into two different strings in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, variables

I have a string called $vehicle that is typically formed like this:

'BMW - 5'

The first part before the ' - ' is the car name and the second part after the ' - ' is the capacity of the vehicle.

How can I turn these into two different strings using preg_replace? I tried different methods such as the /b regex but I failed to make it work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without using a regex at all, using [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$input = "BMW - 5";
$fields = epxlode(" - ", $input);
$name = $fields[0];
$capacity = $fields[1];
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I didn't even know explode() could be used for that.

Comment: you can also use the `list()` for a shorter code like this `list($name, $capacity) = explode(" - ", $input);`

Comment: Thanks @KingKing that actually seems easier to use.